# Echo after header

Tags: javascript, php, header

This is a part of my code. The code is moving to the location, but the echo below is not working. 
I am sure this header is affecting it somehow

```
else {
     header('location: index.php'); 
     echo '<script>
           document.getElementById("nick").value = "invalid email";                                                                          
           document.getElementById("nick").className = "invalidemail"; 
           </script>';
```

Comment: Assuming that there has been no output before the call to `header`, you will be redirecting to `index.php`, so any further statements in this script will be ignored.

Comment: You know what `header: location` does, right?

Comment: So is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read something about header in php functions, you will came to know that nothing gets printed after header as you are giving instructions to redirect on index.php

However to achieve the same, you can use session variables.

So, on the page where you are redirecting to index.php:

```
$_SESSION['error']=true;
header('location: index.php');
```

On index.php, check if session variable is true:

```
if($_SESSION['error']== true)
{
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
             document.getElementById("nick").value = "invalid email";                                                                          
             document.getElementById("nick").className = "invalidemail"; 
           </script>';
}
```